# How to dynamicly forward URLs based on the users IP address

Tags: php, dynamic, forward

I'm working on a PHP script for my homeserver. Sometimes I access the homeserver webpage in my home network (from IP 192.168.192.*) and sometimes from the outside (public IP-address). I've created the following script for this:

```
<?php
    $baseurl = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        if (preg_match("/192.168.192.*/",$baseurl)) {
            $baseurl = "http://192.168.192.100";
            }
        else {
            $baseurl = "http://homeserverwebsite.com";
            }
?>
```

When I use `<?php echo $baseurl; ?>` somewhere on my webpage it works! From the outside it replies `http://homeserverwebsite.com` (adres to my homeserver) and from my internal network `http://192.168.192.100` (which is my homeserver IP).

However there is a problem. For building my links I use the folling code:

```
<a href="<?php $baseurl . ":5000"; ?>" target="_blank">Link to website 1</a>
<a href="<?php $baseurl . ":5001"; ?>" target="_blank">Link to website 2</a>
```

When I click it internaly, it will send me to `http://192.168.192.100` and I want it to send me to `http://192.168.192.100:5000`.

When I use  `<?php echo $baseurl . "5000"; ?>` somewhere on the webpage it works fine, it outputs `http://192.168.192.100:5000` but not when I use it in the  tag. How is this possible? :( It seems like the  doesnt want an URL with URL:PORT links in it if they are generated by PHP? How can I get passed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php $baseurl . ":5000"; ?>"
```

should be

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl . ":5000"; ?>"
```